# status value in wait function and wexitstatus

Tags: c, process, wait, status, wexitstatus

I read this [code](http://rooftrellen.com/blog/computer-systems-a-programmers-perspective-chapter-8-homework-problem/) in an implementation of the system function of unix (problem 8.22):

```
        int status;
        if (wait(&status) > 0) {
             if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                 return WEXITSTATUS(status);
             } else {
                 return status;
             }
        }
```

I don't understand what the if condition is for here: Isn't the status returned by WEXITSTATUS the same as the one in wait? If not, then what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `status` value is a sort of composite value which includes the process "exit status" plus other bits.  From the Linux man page regarding `WEXITSTATUS`:

> If the value of WIFEXITED(stat_val) is non-zero, this macro evaluates
>   to the low-order 8 bits of the status argument that the child process
>   passed to _exit() or exit(), or the value the child process returned
>   from main().